# Using a balanced scale find the minimum and maximum weight of items

Tags: logical-deduction, weighing

There are 1567 items with different weights. The goal is to find the item that has the maximum weight out of the 1567 and the item that has the minimum weight out of the 1567. For this you are allowed to use a balanced scale where only one item can fit on one side of the scale. In what way can this be done in under 2345 measurements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [68 coins with 100 weighings](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55950/68-coins-with-100-weighings) (numbers are different, but the method is identical).

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'm not sure the numbers work out when using the solutions in the linked question. The fact that there are an odd number of coins makes it trickier too. I get 783 weighings to split it into a light and a heavy group, both of size 784 (one unweighed coin occurs in both), then 783 weighings in each group to find the lightest or heaviest, for 783+783+783=2349 weighings in total.